# Download folder and its subfolders using FTPUtil

Tags: java, file, ftp, download, ftputil

I want to download a file from ftp using the [FTPUtil](http://amoebacode.com/media/amoebacode.com/ftp/javadoc/com/amoebacode/ftp/FTPUtil.html) library the java API. Specifically I want to download a folder and its subfolders(if any).
Is there a simple way already implemeted on the FTPUtil ?

other library recommendation is also ok.

thanks

Comment: In what way do you need the files to be downloaded? In a single archive?

Comment: as it is, which means that at the end of the download, the folder(and possibly its sub folders/files recursively) in the ftp server should exit locally.